# Phoenix umbrella app not hot-reloading code

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, umbrella

I have trouble with code reload in my Phoenix umbrella app.

My umbrella is composed of 2 applications : app and app_web. Any change in app_web is hot reloaded as wanted, but I can’t make the same thing work with code in app.

Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are running `mix phx.server` from `apps/app_web`. This is a common pitfall with umbrella projects, where you need to start the server from the root directory of the umbrella project for code reloading to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I actually couldn't run phx.server from the root directory because of this issue https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/2773. I will use phoenix head version until 1.3.2 is released.